# Django: How do you override logfile variable during testing?

Tags: django, django-testing, django-settings, django-login

I'm trying to get my test suite to create a different logfile than the one I use in development, but for some reason the override_settings decorator doesn't seem to be working. When I run the test, the same 'project/project/debug_logfile' is written. Where am I messing up?

```
# settings.py
...
LOGFILE = ROOT + '/debug_logfile'

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
        'standard': {
             'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
             'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false']
        },
        'logfile': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': LOGFILE,
            'maxBytes': 50000,
            'backupCount': 2,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'clients': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'logfile'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        # display the db queries
        #'django.db.backends': {
        #    'handlers': ['console'],
        #    'level': 'DEBUG',
        #}
    }
}

# clients.management.commands.remindmanagers.py

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Creates task reminders and send emails to account and senior \
            managers when their client\'s contracts are about to expire'

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        three_months = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=90)
        # get all contracts that will be completed in the next 3 months
        contracts = Contract.objects.filter(finish__lte=three_months
                                   ).exclude(notices_left=0)

        if not contracts.exists():
            log.info('Tried running but there are no contracts about to expire.')
            return 0
        ...

# tests.test_clients

...
from django.core.management import call_command

@override_settings(LOGFILE=settings.ROOT + "/test_logfile")
class ClientCommandTest(BaseTestCase):
    def _file_exists(file_path):
        return os.path.exists(file_path)

    def test_remindmanagers_no_contracts(self):
        args = []
        kwargs = {}
        #self.assertFalse()
        # since there are no contracts yet, this should create an entry in ROOT + /logfile
        call_command('remindmanagers', *args, **kwargs)                                      # this should log in project/project/test_logfile not debug_logfile
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not enough to **`override_settings`**.
Because logging is configured before **override_settings** take effect.
Call **`configure_logging`** (`django.utils.log`) to change logging settings, and don't forget to return the original settings back.

Look at the example below:

settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'formatter1': {
            'format': 'settings logger: {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'stream': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'formatter1',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'test_logging_override': {
            'handlers': ['stream'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propogate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings
from django.utils.log import configure_logging

class TestLoggingOverride(TestCase):
    def test_logging_override(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger('test_logging_override')
        logger.debug('one')  # settings logger: one
        with override_settings(LOGGING={
            'version': 1,
            'disable_existing_loggers': False,
            'formatters': {
                'formatter1': {
                    'format': 'overridden logger: {message}',  # !!!!
                    'style': '{',
                },
            },
            'handlers': {
                'stream': {
                    'level': 'DEBUG',
                    'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',  # 'class': 'logging.FileHandler'
                    # 'filename': 'path/to/file',  # in case of FileHandler
                    'formatter': 'formatter1',
                },
            },
            'loggers': {
                'test_logging_override': {
                    'handlers': ['stream'],
                    'level': 'DEBUG',
                    'propogate': True,
                },
            },
        }):
            logger.debug('two')  # settings logger: two
            configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)  # really change settings
            logger.debug('three')  # overridden logger: three
        logger.debug('four')  # overridden logger: four
        configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)  # return to native settings
        logger.debug('five')  # settings logger: five
```

Also, you can write tests for logging.

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch, call
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings
from django.utils.log import configure_logging

class TestLoggingOverride(TestCase):
    @patch(
         target='sys.stderr',
         wraps=sys.stderr,  # wraps all of sys.stderr. Remove this line, if you want to disable writing to stderr in this test
     )
     def test_patched_stream_logger(self, mocked_stderr):
         logger = logging.getLogger('test_logging_override')
         with override_settings(LOGGING={
             'version': 1,
             'disable_existing_loggers': False,
             'formatters': {
                 'formatter1': {
                     'format': 'overridden logger: {message}',  # !!!!
                     'style': '{',
                 },
             },
             'handlers': {
                 'stream': {
                     'level': 'DEBUG',
                     'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                     'formatter': 'formatter1',
                 },
             },
             'loggers': {
                 'test_logging_override': {
                     'handlers': ['stream'],
                     'level': 'DEBUG',
                     'propogate': True,
                 },
             },
         }):
             configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)  # really change settings
             logger.debug('lorem ipsum')
         configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)  # return to native settings
         self.assertEqual(
             mocked_stderr.method_calls,
             [call.flush(),
              call.flush(),
              call.write('overridden logger: lorem ipsum\n'),
              call.flush(),
              call.flush(),
              call.flush(),
              call.flush()]
         )
         # print(mocked_stderr.method_calls)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `LOGGING` dict literal contains the variable `LOGFILE`, which gets evaluated immediately when processing the dict literal. By overriding `LOGFILE` later you aren't changing the entry in the `LOGGING` dict because the `LOGFILE` string is simply replaced; the string itself is not mutated, so you end up with `LOGFILE` simply pointing to another string.

I think you should be able to override just the logfile handler with the new filename like so:

```
@override_settings(LOGGING={
  'handlers': {
    'logfile': {
       'filename': settings.ROOT + "/test_logfile"
    }
  }
})
class ClientCommandTest(BaseTestCase):
  ...
```